# Boost Tcp Client Receive Crash

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio, boost-thread

I have been working recently with the Boost library for windows visual studio 2015. I have been recently working on a server and client that can easily transfer data via tcp connection. But recently I was trying to send a Base64 encoded file string to the client which is roughly 366,660 Bytes of data. To do this I split up the data into packets that are about 1000 in size. (not sure what the max size is) But anyway the server sends the data completely fine but when the client receives more than 160,000 bytes it crashes with no exceptions.

Client:

```
try
{
    for (static int i = 1000; i <= sizeofpackets /*(366,660) (currently 170,000 for testing)*/; i += 1000)
    {
        char Buffer[1000];
        memset(Buffer, 0, 1000);
        boost::asio::read(s, boost::asio::buffer(Buffer, 1000));
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

Server:

```
for (int i = 1000; i <= 170000; i += 1000)
{
    std::string NewData = encodedBuffer.substr(i - 1000, i);
    NewData.erase(0, i - 1000);
    boost::asio::write(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(NewData, 1000));
    std::cout << NewData.size() + i - 1000 << std::endl;
    NewData.clear();
}
```

Any comments or suggestion would help greatly!

Comment: What have you tried so far to determine the cause of the crash?

Comment: I debugged it down to boost::asio::read and the buffer gets reset every iteration so not sure what else to check.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your complete code, so it is hard to tell, but your problem might be the way you are handling strings, not the way you are handling the socket transfers (the substr() member function takes a start offset and a size, and it looks like you are trying to use an ever-increasing size for NewData).

The following (complete) code, which uses your client and server code as a reference, but with the string handling changed, does transfer 170000 bytes just fine on my machine, so it may help:

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


namespace
{
    const size_t BIG_MESSAGE_SIZE = 170000;
    const size_t BLOCK_SIZE = 1000;

    void doTX(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, size_t& TXsize)
    {
        char rawBuffer[BIG_MESSAGE_SIZE] = { 0 }; // raw data to send
        std::string encodedBuffer(rawBuffer, BIG_MESSAGE_SIZE);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < BIG_MESSAGE_SIZE; i += BLOCK_SIZE)
        {
            std::string NewData = encodedBuffer.substr(i, BLOCK_SIZE);
            TXsize += boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(NewData, BLOCK_SIZE));
        }
    }

    void doRX(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, size_t& RXsize)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < BIG_MESSAGE_SIZE; i += BLOCK_SIZE)
        {
            char Buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
            memset(Buffer, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
            RXsize += boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(Buffer, BLOCK_SIZE));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Running:" << std::endl;

    int port = 9876;

    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), port);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, endpoint);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket TXsocket(ios);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket RXsocket(ios);

    TXsocket.connect(endpoint);
    acceptor.accept(RXsocket);

    size_t TXsize = 0;
    size_t RXsize = 0;

    doTX(TXsocket, TXsize);
    doRX(RXsocket, RXsize);

    std::cout << TXsize << " " << RXsize << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot send a 366,600 byte string in one packet so I break it up into interval packets of 1000 each. Thats why NewData is changing. I also changed it to 1024 to get the most out of my packets, and it seems that the server sends the string just fine but the client seems to stop at a certain point. https://image.prntscr.com/image/f9595c1acc41437bb37070d96e631731.png

Comment: @Opendn33 yes I see what you are trying to do but unfortunately you didn't post a complete working version of your code so I cannot verify that it is working as you intended. If you can do so I will try to help. If not, I suggest you check the return value at each call of write() and use that to update a running total of how much is actually being sent (see my code as an example) as simply printing out NewData.size() + i - 1000 is not reliable.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I just checked the return data from the byte sent and it was in the millions lol so I fixed it by changing the data type now it only sends 1024. I appreciate the help!